# grep not counting occurrences which span more than one line

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I am using grep to count the occurrences of a particular string in my code, but grep is not counting the occurrences which span more than one line.

I am trying to find occurrences of `` (` ``  including the ones which look like

```
 (
       `
```

Basically, the backtick is in the next line.

I tried so far:

```
 grep -roh -E "\(\s*\`" . | wc -l
```

But it doesn't count them.
Even

```
grep -roh -E "\(\n" . | wc -l
```

this is giving 0.

What would be the solution to this?

Comment: You should probably improve the description of what you want to count. Is the `(` always the first character in the line? Is it always followed only by spaces and then a backtick? Is there always exactly one newline? Zero or one? Any number?

Comment: `grep` does line by line searching. If you want to search for multiple lines, you'll need to use grep's context command line options (-A, -B, and -C) and possibly do another grep.

Answer (score 0):

The following assumes the strings you want to count start with an opening parenthesis, followed by spaces and end with a backtick, with at most one newline in the spaces. We can use `sed` (tested with GNU `sed`) to remove the newlines before passing all this to `grep` and `wc`:

```sh
$ s='abc
text (   
    `
def
   text   (
   `
ghi ( ` (` jkl
'

$ sed -Ez ':a;s/(.*)\([[:blank:]]*\n[[:blank:]]*`(.*)/\1\(`\2/g;ta' <<< "$s"
abc
text (`
def
   text   (`
ghi ( ` (` jkl

$ sed -Ez ':a;s/(.*)\([[:blank:]]*\n[[:blank:]]*`(.*)/\1\(`\2/g;ta' <<< "$s" |
  grep -Eo '\(\s*`'
(`
(`
( `
(`

$ sed -Ez ':a;s/(.*)\([[:blank:]]*\n[[:blank:]]*`(.*)/\1\(`\2/g;ta' <<< "$s" |
  grep -Eo '\(\s*`' | wc -l
4
```

The `sed` script uses the `-z` option to separate lines by NUL characters. It substitutes any of your string that contains a newline by just an opening parenthesis, followed by a backtick and loops as long as there are substitutions.

To apply this on all files under the current directory you will need `find` to concatenate them and pipe to `sed`:

```sh
$ find . -type f -exec cat {} \; |
  sed -Ez ':a;s/(.*)\([[:blank:]]*\n[[:blank:]]*`(.*)/\1\(`\2/g;ta' |
  grep -Eo '\(\s*`' | wc -l
1257
```

Answer (score 0):

```
find -type f -exec cat {} + | tr -d '[:space:]' | grep -oF '(`' | wc -l
```

- `find` catenates contents of all files into a stream
- `tr` reads stream and strips whitespace
- `grep` outputs occurrences of the string (`-o` is GNU extension)
- `wc` counts them

Comment: This will also count occurrences where the opening parenthesis and the backstick are separated by more than zero or one newline. But as the OP is not 100% clear it could be that this is what they want.

Comment: This code will incorrectly match a parenthesis at the end of a file and a backtick at the very start of the next one found by `find`, but perhaps that situation is not likely.